# How to define the Index trait on an object where the data is held in a `RefCell` in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do we define the `Index` trait on an object where the data is held in a `RefCell` in Rust?  Basically, I've an object that I'd like to index where sometimes the data exists and sometimes it does not.  When the data does not exist, I would like to create it and then return the appropriate reference for the indexing operation.  Otherwise, I'd like to index as normal.  As a simplified example of this, we have the code

```rust
// External libraries                                                            
use std::cell::{Ref, RefCell};                                                   
use std::ops::Index;                                                             

// Funny looking vector                                                          
struct MyVec<T> {                                                                
    size: usize,                                                                 
    data: RefCell<Option<Vec<T>>>,                                               
}                                                                                

// Create a full vector                                                          
fn full<T>(size: usize, data: Vec<T>) -> MyVec<T> {                              
    MyVec {                                                                      
        size,                                                                    
        data: RefCell::new(Some(data)),                                          
    }                                                                            
}                                                                                
// Creates an empty vector                                                       
fn empty<T>(size: usize) -> MyVec<T> {                                           
    MyVec {                                                                      
        size,                                                                    
        data: RefCell::new(None),                                                
    }                                                                            
}                                                                                

// Index from the vector                                                         
impl<T> Index<usize> for MyVec<T>                                                
where                                                                            
    T: Clone + Default,                                                          
{                                                                                
    type Output = T;                                                             
    fn index(&self, idx: usize) -> &Self::Output {                               
        // Take out the data for processing                                      
        let data = self.data.replace(None);                                      

        // Make sure the data is full                                            
        let data = match data {                                                  
            None => Some(vec![Default::default(); self.size]),                   
            Some(_) => data,                                                     
        };                                                                       

        // Put the data back inside the vector                                   
        let _ = self.data.replace(data);                                         

        // Return a reference to the element                                     
        Ref::map(self.data.borrow(), |data| match &data {                        
            Some(data) => &data[idx],                                            
            None => unreachable!(),                                              
        })                                                                       
    }                                                                            
}                                                                                

// Test our functions                                                            
fn main() {                                                                      
    // Create an empty vector                                                    
    let a = empty::<f32>(3);                                                     

    // Print a value                                                             
    println!("a(1): {}", a[1]);                                                  
}
```

This does not compile and returns the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/test02.rs:48:9
   |
48 | /         Ref::map(self.data.borrow(), |data| match &data {
49 | |             Some(data) => &data[idx],
50 | |             None => unreachable!(),
51 | |         })
   | |__________^ expected &T, found struct `std::cell::Ref`
   |
   = note: expected type `&T`
              found type `std::cell::Ref<'_, T>`
help: consider borrowing here
   |
48 |         &Ref::map(self.data.borrow(), |data| match &data {
49 |             Some(data) => &data[idx],
50 |             None => unreachable!(),
51 |         })
   |

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Of course, `Ref` is not the same as `&`.  That said, how can this be fixed?

In case it matters, I don't necessarily *need* a `RefCell`.  In reality, I've an enumerate type with different options.  However, the case remains the same.  Sometimes the data exists.  Sometimes the data doesn't.  When the data doesn't exist, I'd like to create it before we index.

Comment: You cannot do this because it is unsound. Inserting into the vector may cause it to reallocate, which would invalidate all existing references to its members. You need a `&mut` reference to guarantee no existing references, which makes the `RefCell` extraneous.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make a `get(&'a self, usize)` method that returns `Ref<'a, T>`, but that's (also) not compatible with the `Index` trait

Comment: @trentcl I would be fine with only allowing mutable references, but `IndexMut` requires `Index`.  Is there a workaround that still preserves the operators?

Comment: Another approach could be to use an arena, or to wrap the `T`s in `Box`es so they have stable addresses and use a bit of `unsafe` to lie about the lifetimes. [Here's a post I made on users.rust-lang.org, solving a similar problem](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/a-lazily-initialized-map/18101/9); perhaps that will help.

Comment: OnceCell may help here